# How do I replace all the blocked google ads (with an image) on my page instead of just the first one? Trouble with CSS selectors

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to replace all blocked ads (for users with adblock) with an image politely asking to have the site white-listed.

This code wasn't written by me at all- it's taken from a site that I can't seem to track down again. I'm a little embarrassed to post here, but I've wasted hours on what *seems* like a simple fix.

```
    <script> 

  window.onload = function(){ 

    setTimeout(function() { 

      var ad = document.querySelector("ins.adsbygoogle");

      if (ad && ad.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, "").length == 0) {

        ad.style.cssText = 'display:block !important'; 

        ad.innerHTML = '<img src="image here"></img>';

      }

    }, 2000);
  }; 

</script>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
var ad = document.querySelectorAll("ins.adsbygoogle");
```

But it didn't seem to help.

Comment: Did you try a `for` loop...?

Comment: check out what [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) does... and then check out [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). You have to use the all one, and it will return an array. Then you just loop through that array.

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your ads:

```
var ads = document.querySelectorAll("ins.adsbygoogle");

for (var ad in ads) {    
      if (ad.innerHTML.replace(/\s/g, "").length == 0) {    
          ad.style.cssText = 'display:block !important';     
          ad.innerHTML = '<img src="image here"></img>';    
      }
}
```

Comment: The loop didn't seem to help, I only ended up with an issue where my image didn't load at all.